# Proving existence of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces, absolute-value

Show that the pair $(\mathbb{N}, d)$, where $d:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$
d(u,v)=\frac{|u-v|}{uv}
$$
for $u,v\in\mathbb{N}$, is a metric space.

I have managed to prove the first two conditions of a metric (equality and symmetry). I have trouble with proving the triangular condition. Here is what I came up with
$$
d(x,y) + d(y,z) 
= \frac{|x-y|}{xy} + \frac{|y-z|}{yz} 
= \frac{z\,|x-y| + x\,|y-z|}{xyz}
$$
and
$$
d(x,z) = \frac{|x-z|}{xz} 
= \frac{|x-y+y-z|}{xz} 
\leq \frac{|x-y|+|y-z|}{xz}
$$

We can clearly see from that the following inequation is true:
$$
\frac{|x-z|}{xz} 
\leq \frac{|x-y|+|y-z|}{xz} 
$$

I do not know if there is a way to continue the further prove. Am I doing it in the right way? How can I prove this third condition?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please use MathJax when you ask a question. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How can you "clearly see from that the following inequation is true"?$$\frac{|x-y|+|y-z|}{xz}\le\frac{z|x-y|+x|y-z|}{xyz}$$

Comment: This is a metric space by [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) from the subset $\{1/n\mid n\in\Bbb N^*\}$ of $\Bbb R,$ equipped with the usual distance. $$d(u,v)=\left|\frac1v-\frac1u\right|$$and $$\left|\frac1z-\frac1x\right|\le\left|\frac1z-\frac1y\right|+\left|\frac1y-\frac1x\right|.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval because the set is N^{+} (natural numbers) which means that x,y,z are clearly greater than zero. We have 3 products with these numbers so the right side of inequality is bigger. But I still don't know how to prove it mathematically without using words but symbols. But I will try to see the metric you have shown.

Comment: Actually that inequality was wrong. It is a good idea to have removed it, but not to have reintroduced heavier notations (this is why I took the liberty to restore the previous formatting). As for the proof you wanted, it was provided in my last comment, which I just edited below as an answer. (Meanwhile, 2 other similar answers were posted.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray}  d (n_1, n_2) & = & \left| \frac{1}{n_1} - \frac{1}{n_2} \right| . \nonumber \end{eqnarray}
Therefore, for every $n_1,n_2,n_3\in\mathbb{N}^+$ one has
\begin{eqnarray} d (n_1, n_2) & = & \left| \left( \frac{1}{n_1} - \frac{1}{n_3} \right) +  \left( \frac{1}{n_3} - \frac{1}{n_2} \right) \right| \nonumber\\  & \leqslant & \left| \frac{1}{n_1} - \frac{1}{n_3} \right| + \left|  \frac{1}{n_3} - \frac{1}{n_2} \right| \nonumber\\  & = & d (n_1, n_3) + d (n_3, n_2) \nonumber .\end{eqnarray}

Comment: And we can add absolute value to the denominator because n_1 and n_2 are in the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, the expression of your metric is the same as the one I wrote because $n_1$ and $n_2$ are positive integers (natural numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $d(n,m)=|\frac1n-\frac1m|$ so instead of considering $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^+$ you can consider $x,y \in \{\frac1n : n \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$  and distance function $d^*(x,y)=|x-y|$ which we know satisfies the triangle inequality. Note that we didn't do anything fancy here, it's just the substitution $x=\frac1n$ to get the new metric on this new set.

Now since $d^*(x,z) \leq d^*(x,y) + d^*(y,z)$ so that $|x-z|\leq |x-y|+|y-z|$ and substituting back we have $|\frac1n-\frac1p|\leq |\frac1n-\frac1m|+|\frac1m-\frac1p|$ which proves $d(n,p) \leq d(n,m) + d(m,p)$ on $\mathbb{N}^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $(\mathbb{N}, d)$
is a metric space by [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure)
from the subset $\{1/n\mid n∈\Bbb N\}$
of $\Bbb R$,
equipped with the usual distance.

More explicitely:
$$
d(u,v)=\left|{\frac1v-\frac1u}\right|
$$
and
$$\left|\frac1z-\frac1x\right|\le\left|\frac1z-\frac1y\right|+\left|\frac1y-\frac1x\right|,$$
hence
$$d(x,z)\le d(y,z)+d(x,y).$$